# unable to pull department and emailaddress attributes from aduser and write to CSV

Tags: powershell

Using this cmdlet pipe and the email address will not write properly to a CSV.

```
get-adgroupmember "groupName" | select name,samAccountName,emailAddress | export-csv [path] -notype
```

this returns the Name and Samaccountnames just fine, but for email, it just has Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection for each entry.

Also when trying to select department, it's just blank.

Any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping the results from get-adgroupmember to get-aduser will be able to give you the objects you are looking for like so.

```
 Get-ADGroupMember groupName | Get-ADUser -Properties name,samAccountName,emailAddress,department | select name,samAccountName,emailAddress,department | export-csv fileName.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the returned object from `Get-ADGroupMember` doesn't have an "EmailAddress" or "Department" property:

```
TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal
...
distinguishedName Property              System.String distinguishedName {get;set;}
name              Property              System.String name {get;}
objectClass       Property              System.String objectClass {get;set;}
objectGUID        Property              System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ...
SamAccountName    Property              System.String SamAccountName {get;set;}
SID               Property              System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier SID {get;set;}
```